# Ошибка в скрипте php

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api, denwer, сокеты

Здраствуйте! Я создаю приложение для вконтакте, и мне надо отправить запрос к `api` на `php`, 
но неполучается, курл на моем хостинге отсутвует поэтому пришол к выводу что надо делать через сокеты, но неполучается.
Вот код.

```
<?php
$socket = fsockopen('ssl://api.vkontakte.ru', 443, $errno, $errstr, 60);

//если fsockopen вернула false, то завершаем работу скрипта и выводим текст и номер ошибки
if(!$socket)die("$errstr($errno)");

//собираем данные
$data = "uid=1&access_token=1c5553a351f297fe1f4756e93b1fa4792c91f821f85e9ff8185e85cb97579bd";

//пишем в сокет метод, URI и протокол 
fwrite($socket, "POST /method/audio.get HTTP/1.1\r\n");
//а также имя хоста
fwrite($socket, "Host: api.vkontakte.ru\r\n");

//теперь отправляем заголовки
//Content-type должен быть applicaion/x-www-form-urlencoded
fwrite($socket,"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
//размер передаваемых данных передаем в заголовке Content-length
fwrite($socket,"Content-length:".strlen($data)."\r\n");
//типы принимаемых данных. */* означает, что принимаем все типы данных
fwrite($socket,"Accept:*/*\r\n");
//представимся оперой
fwrite($socket,"User-agent:Opera 10.00\r\n");
fwrite($socket,"\r\n");

//теперь передаем данные
fwrite($socket,"$data\r\n");
fwrite($socket,"\r\n");

//теперь читаем и выводим ответ
$answer = '';
while(!feof($socket)){
    $answer.= fgets($socket, 4096);
}
echo $answer;

//закрываем сокет
fclose($socket);
?>
Помогите пожалуйста.
```

Comment: Какая ошибка, можно поподробнее?

Как минимум, ssl://https://api.vkontakte.ru/ - уже ошибка форматирования.

Comment: Ну, для начала, убираем слэш / с конца строки, а то .ru/:443 выглядит странно, не так ли? Равно как и www перед api. Т.е. проще говоря, пишите ssl://api.vkontakte.ru

Напишите результат. Остальное потом, если что.

Comment: У ваc php.ini не продублирован где-нибудь, например в папке Windows или Windows/System32? Т.е. где-то в фолдерах, которые указаны в переменной окружения $PATH? Поищите, только не забудьте указать в настройках поиска, чтобы система искала бы в системных папках тоже.

Comment: Вам проще тогда через Гугл. Наберите Denwer SSL, полно результатов с обсуждениями. Там еще пару ДЛЛ надо прикрутить, судя по всему, но все-таки решения разные. С XAMPP серевером проблем с SSL не было,если мне память не изменяет.
P.S. Версия Денвера последняя? Может стоит обновить?

Comment: Ничего, в паках винды и систем 32 нету, скопировал php.ini туда но не фига, такаяже ошибка, потом скачал дллки php-openssl.dll и php-sockets.dll но тоже не фига, вот решил скинуть код на хостинг, но из-за него пишется ошибка 500. что делать я почти в истерике..
P.S. Версия денвера последня..

Comment: А зачем такой изврат ? Используйте cURL

Comment: Прочитайте мой вопрос внимательнее...))))курла на моем хостинге нет...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сорь, чето не увидел про курл.

Ну а так не вариант ?

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' . PHP_EOL,
        'content' => "uid=1&access_token=1c5553a351f297fe1f4756e93b1fa4792c91f821f85e9ff8185e85cb97579bd",
    ),
));

$answer = file_get_contents(
    $file = "https://api.vkontakte.ru/",
    $use_include_path = false,
    $context
);
```

Comment: Пишет мне такую фигню..>>>>

Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in Z:\home\player\www\vko.php on line 14

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.vkontakte.ru/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in Z:\home\player\www\vko.php on line 14

Answer (score 3):

Я вот обратил внимание только сейчас, Вы используете локальный сервер для тестировки, буква Z в имени диска подсказывает мне, что используете Денвер. Итак:

1. Найдите php.ini в Z:\usr\local\php5\
2. Откройте его любым текстовым редактором
3. Найдите строку ;extension=php_openssl.dll и раскомментируйте ее, т.е. уберите ;
4. Сохраните и перезапустите сервер.

Всего делов.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как у вас.. Но кроме как на вписанных серверах в приложении для которого вы получили токен, работать ничего не должно. Там идет привязка к серверу! Контакт отправляет данные если скрипт работает из указанного в приложении сервера. В остальных случаях токен будет не рабочим!